# Outputting a array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, class

```
public class Set {
    private int[] num;

    public Set(int ... nums){
        this.num = nums;
    }
    public int getSet(){

        for (int results : this.num){
            return results;
        }
    }

}
```

I wrote this class as a test to see try and output an array of integers using a method but I'm having troubles

Here is the driver program:

```
public class SetTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set set = new Set();

    set.Set(1,2,3);

    set.getSet();

   }
   }
```

I'm stumped on what to do, I get this error also "The method IntegerSet(int, int, int) is undefined for the type Set"

Comment: Where is `IntegerSet`? And don't name your class with the pre-defined class or interface names.

Comment: You have a class named `Set` and then you try to make an instance from class `IntegerSet`. What is `IntegerSet`? In method `getSet` you have a `for loop` trying to return every integer. This won't work as you think. It will return only the first integer. It will get into the loop and will return the first integer, where the method was called. Nothing else is executed after the return. No more loops

Comment: You are getting right error. Where you defined  IntegerSet(int, int, int) method in Set ?

Comment: So if the for loop only returns the 1st integer, how would I write the code to return every single integer (1,2,3)?

Answer (score 2):

Your type seems to be called `Set` not `IntegerSet`, but even if we assume that is a typo on the next line(`set.IntegerSet(1,2,3);`) in main you are calling a constructor explicitly which you are never supposed to do. Instead pass the arguments when you are constructing the `IntegerSet`:

```
IntegerSet set = new IntegerSet(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined a constructor as below

```
public Set(int ... nums){
        this.num = nums;
    }
```

To create a new instance of Set using the constructor above, you want to do

```
Set objSet = new Set(1,2,3);
objSet.getSet();
```

IntegerSet class in your code doesn't seem to exist, which makes your code invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would help if you clarified what `IntegerSet` is as opposed to the `Set` class you provided.  However, your problem is that you are trying to call a *constructor* as though it were a method.  So this is valid:

```
IntegerSet set = new IntegerSet(1, 2, 3);
```

Note that the arguments must be passed to the class *when it is created* - this is the definition of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Set {
private int[] num;

public Set(int a, int b, int c) {
    num = new int[] { a, b, c };
}

public void getSet() {

    for (int results : this.num) {
        System.out.println(results);
    }

}

}
```

Your Set class should be like above. And SetTest should be like below.

```
public class SetTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set set = new Set(1, 2, 3);

    set.getSet();
}

}
```

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to edit it. I made the right corrections now. But yeah it was suppose to be Set set = new Set (1,2,3). I thought doing for (int results : this.num) would return the array list but it doesn't and gives me error "The method IntegerSet(int, int, int) is undefined for the type Set"

Comment: @user2057961 You can return the integer array . You can't return each element in for loop.

Comment: I see what you did with public Set(int a, int b, int c) {
 num = new int[] { a, b, c }; but what if I didn't want 3 integers, and wanted 4 or 5 instead? would (list ... num) be better? And if I can only return the integer array how would I return each element to check reference with another set?

Comment: (list ... num)?? You mean ArrayList<Integer>list?

Comment: Haven't read on ArrayList< > yet, i'll get going on that, thanks for your help :)